# Chi Sqaure Test - Why Null (H0) and Alternative (H1) hypothesis testing result is coming wrong or there is something wrong in my understanding

Tags: python, scipy

```
from scipy.stats import chi2_contingency
 
# defining the table

data = [[1,2,3,4,5,], [10,20,30,40,50]]

stat, p, dof, expected = chi2_contingency(data)
 
# interpret p-value
alpha = 0.05
print("p value is " + str(p))
if p <= alpha:
    print('Dependent (reject H0)')
else:
    print('Independent (H0 holds true)')
```

output is:
p value is 1.0
Independent (H0 holds true)

Even though you can clearly see that there is a strong correlation between two variables and they are dependent on each other.
I took the code from  -
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pearsons-chi-square-test/

Comment: It looks like this question is due to a misunderstanding of the statistics rather than the code, so [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) would be a more appropriate forum.

Answer (score 0):

A Pearson's chi-square test is a statistical test for categorical data. It is used to determine whether your data are significantly different from what you expected. I recommend you read: [https://www.scribbr.com/statistics/chi-square-tests/#:~:text=A%20Pearson's%20chi%2Dsquare%20test,different%20from%20what%20you%20expected](https://www.scribbr.com/statistics/chi-square-tests/#:%7E:text=A%20Pearson%27s%20chi%2Dsquare%20test,different%20from%20what%20you%20expected).
For numeric data, if you want to check correlation you can use pearson correlation coefficent (please also read about this if you cant find a good source tell me and I will add a link)

Here is how you can do it, I kept most of your code the same.

```
from scipy.stats import pearsonr

# defining the table

data = [[1,2,3,4,5,], [10,20,30,40,50]]

corr_coefficient, p_value = pearsonr(data[0], data[1])
 
# interpret p-value
alpha = 0.05
print("p value is " + str(p))
if p <= alpha:
    print('Correlated (reject H0)')
else:
    print('Not Correlated (Fail to Reject H0)')
```

output:
p value is 1.0
Independent (H0 holds true)

**Please also remember to never say H0 is true, because we always fail to reject H0. This is because even though our HA was wrong, H0 can also still be wrong for other reasons.**